# shall+be+ ing Verb structure

Tags: future

Why does one use shall+be+ing instead of will? What are the functions of be and V+ing?

I shall be focusing on the mechanisms that govern individual`s choices at and beyond school-leaving age and trying to explain why some pupils leave while others stay on,..

Comment: Please clarify your question, what do you mean instead of will?

Answer (score 0):

"Shall" is used in the first singular and plural person. "I shall open the door." "We shall never go there again."
We use the future simple in predictions about the future, for on-the spot decisions. for promises,threats,warnings,requests,hopes and offers.
We use the future continuous for an action which will be in progress at a stated time.

Comment: There are many different ways of deciding whether to use *shall* or *will.*  The method given here is antiquated and never really had any justification behind it.

Comment: of course there are many ways, but I I don't think that Per wanted me to write every single grammar rule that exists. The method given here is written in every grammar book of English,so I don't understand your point!